# Related Products template customize

Tags: magento2, template, addtocart, custom, related-products

How do you change the related products template output. Instead select all I would like to add a "add to cart" button to all related products and remove checkboxes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, Magento uses the same template for product related, upsell, crosssel and new products content widget. This template comes from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`.

If we want to custom this template, we should copy it to our current theme: `app/design/frontend/{Vendor Theme}/{Theme name}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml`.

Comment: How can we get customtype and products in items.phtml