# Magento 2 Related products add to cart button issue

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I'm using Magento 2 and I've noticed that on the related products block , on the product page , the add to cart button for the related products is actually a check box, and not a properly button.. is there any setting for that to be a properly button ?

Comment: Hi, i'm having the same issue. I was able to get the button added after changing $showCart = true. but how do i get rid of the checkbox?

Comment: @KrisWen Change **$canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();** to **$canItemsAddToCart = false;**

Comment: @MaddocksL Thank you, i have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default Magento, there is no setting option in Admin for Add to Cart button on the related products block. If we want to custom the related, upsell, crosssel and new product template, we should override this template `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`.

Change `$showCart = true;` in case - related product.

We can refer here: [Related Products template customize](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112438/related-products-template-customize/112450#112450)

Comment: I was able to get the button added after changing $showCart = true. but how do i get rid of the checkbox?

Comment: @KrisWen "$canItemsAddToCart = false;"

Answer (score 3):

For displaying the Add To Cart button, edit the below-mentioned file

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

```
$showCart = true;
```

Comment: I was able to get the button added after changing $showCart = true. but how do i get rid of the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the checkboxes (hilariously terrible UX choice! Having 'add to cart' checkboxes but then no 'add to cart' button visible?! So the user has to scroll back up and click the main product add to cart button to add a related product? Oh Magento... *VOMIT* )

Set this in items.phtml:

```
$canItemsAddToCart = false;
```

Clear caches etc.