# How to remove related products check boxes on magento2

Tags: magento2, related-products

I've used `app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml` to set `$showCart = true;` so that an **Add to Cart** button is used for related products rather than **checkboxes**.

```
<?php
switch ($type = $block->getType()) {

    case 'related-rule':
        if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
            $type = 'related';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'related_products_list';
            $title = __('Related Products');
            $items = $block->getAllItems();
            $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
            $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();
            $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = true; 
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
        }
    break;
```

Is there a way for me to remove the checkboxes for adding the related products to the cart?

I know I could use CSS to simply hide the checkboxes but am wondering if there is a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I found these posts to be helpful in overriding the checkboxes on the Related Products and replacing with Add to Cart buttons:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/230155
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/113783

In `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

Change `$canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();` to `$canItemsAddToCart = false;` in the switch statement, case: `related-rule` and/or `related`.

Some template customization may come after this to completely remove the checkboxes, and I suggest copying this vendor file into your theme

> app/design/frontend/`Vendor`/`theme`/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it by remove input checkbox from this line on same file.

```
<?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                                    <div class="field choice related">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related" id="related-checkbox<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                                        <label class="label" for="related-checkbox<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span></label>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
```

Above code will show check box. now just replace this line with below code.

```
<?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                                    <div class="field choice related">
                                        <label class="label" for="related-checkbox<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span></label>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
```