# Add to Cart, Add to wishlist like product list page on related products

Tags: magento2, addtocart, related-products, magento2.2.4

How to display add to block on related products similar to it is displaying on list page?

Comment: The concept of related product is whenever you add any product from product details page then if check any related product's checkbox then that related product will also be added to cart with the product you have added. Thats why there is not add to cart button. If you want to use add to cart and wishlist button on related products then use upsell instead of related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to show **add to cart, add to wish-list** just like as on list page for related product on product view page.

As you know for showing `related`, `upsell` product there is a common file located at

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list\items.phtml
```

Copy above file to your theme, if not exist.

You can see in this phtml there is `switch case` for related and upsell product with some option.

There is already Add to cart button is available in this phtml, but with following condition:

`if ($showAddTo || $showCart):`

That means you need to set `true` to both above variables. Search **$showAddTo** and **$showCart** for **related case** and you will need to change

**$showCart = true;**

from

**$showCart = false;**

Above code will enable add to cart.

**Note:** If you need to hide add to cart checkbox and its label, it can be easily hide using CSS