# Magento 2.2.3 Related Products add to cart button issue

Tags: magento2, addtocart, magento2.2.3, related-products

i'm just wondering if anybody faced with following issue.
I have enabled "add to card" button on my Related products as per this
[article](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113778/magento-2-related-products-add-to-cart-button-issue)

Now button appeared but the problem is that is actually does not work, it point just to checkout/cart/ link

will really appreciate any comments, thanks!

Comment: Gents, anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento, there is no setting option in Admin for Add to Cart button on the related products block. If we want to custom the related, upsell, crosssel and new product template, we should override this template `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`.

Change `$showCart = true;` in case - related product.

We can refer here: [Related Products template customize](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112438/related-products-template-customize/112450#112450)

[source](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/139891/37303)